# Check whether the URL scheme is HTTP or HTTPS

Tags: php, http, https

I'm using the following code to add `http://` to the URL.

```
(substr(strtolower($url), 0, 7) == 'http://'?"":"http://").$url
```

but how can I check whether the original URL contains `https`? I don't want to use an *OR* clause.

Comment: "I don't want to use an or". Why not?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
preg_match("@^https?://@", $url)
```

Comment: Please help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code writing service, by augmenting your code-only answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 10):

**Answer**

```
echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME);
```

**Reference**

docs https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

`parse_url(string $url, int $component = -1): mixed`

`parse_url` function parses a URL and returns an associative array containing any of the various components of the URL that are present. The values of the array elements are not URL decoded.

This function is not meant to validate the given URL, it only breaks it up into the above listed parts. Partial and invalid URLs are also accepted, parse_url() tries its best to parse them correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and a regular expression on your url :

```
preg_match(^http(s)?://);
```

If it returns true, then your URL is ok, whether it uses http of https.

Comment: you forgot both string and regex delimiters ;)

Comment: you should have written preg_match('/^http(s)?:\/\//', $url)

Answer (score 0):

```
strncmp($url, 'https:', 6) === 0
```

Comment: Please help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code writing service, by augmenting your code-only answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http'
```

Comment: Please help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code writing service, by augmenting your code-only answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use [parse_url()](https://www.php.net/parse_url) function.
Like this :

```php
if (empty($url['scheme'])) {
   $url = 'https://' . $url;
}
```