# Check whether url contains http:// or https://

Tags: php, http

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if the url is contains the http or https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334491/check-if-the-url-is-contains-the-http-or-https)

What is the code to figure out whether the given URL contains `http://` or `https://` at the beginning using PHP and regular expressions?

Comment: [`strpos` documentation](http://gr.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), first example.

Comment: Yes Mr Tomalak - if I knew regular expressions I would solve it myself and really don't need this kind of comments here - I'm trying to find the answer rather then read pointless comments like this one.

Answer (score 39):

you can use [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url)

```
<?php
   $url = parse_url('https://example.org');

   if ($url['scheme'] == 'https') {
       // is https;
   }
?>
```

Comment: simple and efficient !

Answer (score 13):

```
if (substr($string, 0, 7) == "http://") {
   $res = "http";
}

if (substr($string, 0, 8) == "https://") {
   $res = "https";
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Maybe this could help

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'];
```

Comment: This returns "HTTP/1.1", nothing to do with https.

Comment: He asked how to get the protocol from an url, which might not be necessarily the current page, it could be a generic string and in that case the array $_SERVER would be completely useless (not to mention the key 'SERVER_PROTOCOL' is wrong because it doesn't tell if the connection is SSL). If the string to parse is also the page url then you could use $_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"] which returns 'http' or  'https' or $_SERVER["HTTPS"] which returns 1 if the scheme is https.