# How to get all links on a page that start with a https in link - PHP

Tags: php, regex, laravel, url-rewriting

I'm trying to get all the links on a page. So for example if a user types in https://laravel.com/ in the input field they will see all the links on that page.

I already got the concept working. Here is part of the code I have:

```
$website = request('website_url');

$pureURL = 'http://www.'.$website.'/';
$doc = new \DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($pureURL);

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link){
    $linkDetail[] = array('url' => $link->getAttribute('href'));
}

$pageLinks = $linkDetail;

return view('api.index', compact('result'));
```

My frontend code:

```
@foreach($pageLinks as $key => $link)
        {{ $link['url'] }}<br />
@endforeach
```

This is what I get:

[image: Page Links]

The problem is, I just want to get all the links that start with **https**. I want to avoid the links that have a /doc in them and so on.
How would I go about doing that. Im not really good with regex, but I know there is a way you can use that.

Comment: you can use `strpos` function to check if href contains https or not. something like this `if (strpos($link->getAttribute('href'), 'https') !== false) {`

Comment: use parse_url see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7468309/check-whether-url-contains-http-or-https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `parse_url()` to check protocol?

```
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link){
    if (parse_url($link->getAttribute('href'), PHP_URL_SCHEME) === 'https') {
        $linkDetail[] = array('url' => $link->getAttribute('href'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thats just what I wanted. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

```
$website = request('website_url');

$pureURL = 'http://www.'.$website.'/';
$doc = new \DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($pureURL);

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link){
$url = $link->getAttribute('href');
    if (strpos($url, 'https') !== 0) {
        continue;
    }
    $linkDetail[] = array('url' => $url);
}

$pageLinks = $linkDetail;

return view('api.index', compact('result'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check if the String starts with HTTPS and only then push it into the array? For instance:

```
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link){
   if (strpos($link, 'https://') !== FALSE)
      $linkDetail[] = array('url' => $link->getAttribute('href'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^https.*[^doc|avoid_end]$
```

something like that https://regex101.com/r/I4ebAR/1 ?

```
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link){
    $linkTmp = $link->getAttribute('href');
    if (preg_match('/^https.*[^doc|avoid_end]$/')) {
        $linkDetail[] = ['url' => $linkTmp];
    }
}
```